# Do an Ajax call on Fancybox when closing

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Afternoon,
i would like to perform an ajax call when i close the fancybox below is my current code, and i would like to know if i can add an ajax call so i can basically update my DB.

```
 $(".print-shipping").fancybox({
    maxWidth: 800,
    maxHeight: 600,
    fitToView: false,
    width: '80%',
    height: '80%',
    autoSize: false,
    closeClick: false,
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    afterClose: function () { parent.location.reload(true); }
});
```

Comment: Seemed a bit mean that you were voted down on this question... for no apparent reason :/

Comment: I get that a lot, i think people are just trying to up their stats etc most of the time. Same with Edits. I had some where they seem to remove what i think are vital bits of text. Oh well life goes on :)

Comment: Well, I voted you back up - screw them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".print-shipping").fancybox({
  afterClose: function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: 'url_to_script',
      type: 'post',
      success : function(res) {
         parent.location.reload(true); 
      }
   });
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add any code you want into the afterClose function(). This can be an ajax call or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

call your ajax function like this:

```
...
afterClose: function () { callAjax();}

function callAjax(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "update.php",
    success(function() { 
      parent.location.reload(true);
    });
  }
```